# Android multiple EditText with OnTextChangedListener

Tags: android, android-edittext

this is really strange, yesterday I asked the question [Yesterdays question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762661/android-multiple-edittext-cant-implement-listener) how to implement multiple editText listeners to avoid duplicating my code. I was kindly provided an answer (which I swear I tried out) but today I am getting no where with it. I am trying to do the following but am getting an `Cannot instantiate the type TextWatcher` error when trying to setup the tw Textwatcher.

```
**TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher();**

intTextValue.addTextChangedListener(tw);
```

any help would be much appreciated. its starting to drive me a little crazy.

Ultimately I am trying to get to the following situation (which should be simple right??).

```
public class myClass extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener, TextWatcher {
private EditText et;
private EditText et1;
private EditText et2;
private int whoHasFocus= 0;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout1);


        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
        et.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        et.addTextChangedListener(tw);

        et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
        et1.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        et1.addTextChangedListener(tw);

        et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
        et2.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        et2.addTextChangedListener(tw);

}

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.et:
                whoHasFocus =1;
                break;
            case R.id.et1:
                whoHasFocus =2;
                break;
            case R.id.et2:
                whoHasFocus=3;
                break;              
            }


        }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        switch (whoHasFocus) {
            case 1:
                //do code
                break;
            case 2:
                //do code
                break;
            case 3:
                //do code
                break;              
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a TextWatcher instance, just use "this"

```
et.addTextChangedListener(this);
et1.addTextChangedListener(this);
et2.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

Comment: this is really strange, why didn't that work for me earlier! oh well maybe a case of wood for the trees. thank you very much for a prompt reply. :)

Comment: will u please explain this a more i am not getting how could i use this i am new in android

Answer (score 0):

[TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) is an interface. You cannot instanciate interfaces. A class needs to implement the interface and this class can be instanciated. So you need to create a class, doesnt matter if anonymous class or not, and instanciate this.

Example:

```
TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that ids are correct
R.id.et is used for all the three EditText s

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, but here's how I do it in a programmatic way if you don't know ahead of time how many listeners you'll need.  Just have a function return a new listener every time you create a new view and then attach it to that view.

```
private TextWatcher getTextWatcher() {
    return new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
}
```